# How to pass data from angular to node controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

my Front end html and controller:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
 $scope.selectedBrands = [];
  
  $scope.selectBrand = function(selectedPhone) {
   // If we deselect the brand
   if ($scope.selectedBrands.indexOf(selectedPhone.brandname) === -1) {
     // Deselect all phones of that brand
     angular.forEach($scope.phones, function(phone) {
       if (phone.brandname === selectedPhone.brandname) {
         phone.selected = false;
        }
      });
    }
  }
  
  $scope.checkSelectedPhones = function() {
   var modelNames = [];
    var aletrMsg= '';
   angular.forEach($scope.phones, function(phone) {
     if (phone.selected) {
       modelNames.push(phone);
        aletrMsg += 'Brand : '+ phone.brandname + 'Phone Name: '+ phone.modelname + ' : Price: '+ phone.price +', ';
      }
    });
    alert(modelNames.length ? aletrMsg : 'No phones selected!');
  }
  var brand ="Nokia";
  $http.get('http://192.168.1.4:3000/shops1').success(function(data, status,response)
{ 
  
console.log(data);
});

 $scope.phones = [{
    id: "986745",
    brandname: "Lumia",
    modelname: "Lumia 735 TS"
  }, {
    id: "896785",
    brandname: "Lumia",
    modelname: "Lumia 830"
  }, {
    id: "546785",
    brandname: "Lumia",
    modelname: "Lumia 510"
  }, {
    id: "144745",
    brandname: "Asha",
    modelname: "Asha 230"
  }, {
    id: "986980",
    brandname: "Asha",
    modelname: "Asha Asn01"
  }, {
    id: "586980",
    brandname: "Asha",
    modelname: "Nokia Asha Dual sim"
  }, {
    id: "986980",
    brandname: "Asha",
    modelname: "Asha 540"
  }];
});

myApp.filter('unique', function() {
  return function(collection, keyname) {
    var output = [], 
        keys = [];

    angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
      var key = item[keyname];
      if(keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
        keys.push(key);
        output.push(item);
      }
    });

    return output;
  };
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <button ng-click="checkSelectedPhones()">
    Check selected phones
  </button>
  
  <div ng-repeat="phone in phones | unique:'brandname'">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="'{{phone.brandname}}'" ng-false-value="''" ng-model="selectedBrands[$index]" ng-change="selectBrand(phone)">  
      {{phone.brandname}}
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <br>
  
  <div ng-repeat="brand in selectedBrands track by $index" ng-if="brand">
    {{brand}}
    <div ng-repeat="phone in phones" ng-if="phone.brandname === brand">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="phone.selected" >  
        {{phone.modelname}}
        
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i have made routes and controllers in node(express.js).i am struggling to pass data for this 
For example i have tried this its working but from htm i dono how to pass values

```
find({
    'Categories.brandname':'Nokia',
    'Categories.models.name':'Lumia',
     'Categories.models.submodel.name':
    {'$all':[ 'Lumia 735 TS', 'Lumia 510']}
})
```

Dynamically i need to pass data for brandname ,models.name,models.submodel.name
i have enclosed my html .from html how to pass data for find ?any one help me out

my backend routes:

```
app.route('/shops1/:shopPhone')
        .get(shops.read)
        .put(shops.update)
        .delete(shops.delete);

    // Finish by binding the Shop middleware
    app.param('shopPhone', shops.shopByPhone);
```

Controller:

```
exports.shopByPhone= function(req, res) {

 Shop.find({
    'Categories.brandname':'Nokia',
    'Categories.models.name':'Lumia',
     'Categories.models.submodel.name':
    {'$all':[ 'Lumia 735 TS', 'Lumia 510']}
}).sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, shops) {
                if (err) {
                         return res.status(400).send({
                                 message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                         });
                } else {
                         res.jsonp(shops);
                 }
         });
 };
```

if i pass static data from controller i am getting data what i expected but  i dono how to pass from angular 
check my demo here brand i already mentioned [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kLzfru76/11/)

Comment: I think you have to create new route for that otherwise you have to combine all 3 param in single string by # or any other char and have to split in express side and have to search

Comment: how to combine pls can you help me out. i am struggling in this

Comment: you have to search based on 3 params right?

Comment: s right find({
    'Categories.brandname':'Nokia',
    'Categories.models.name':'Lumia',
     'Categories.models.submodel.name':
    {'$all':[ 'Lumia 735 TS', 'Lumia 735 TS']}
})

Comment: when express api is call from angular function do one thing make one string and combine all param in one string like var search_param = "Nokia#Lumia#Microsoft" and pass to node server and split this string in express by #

Comment: how can i do pls change fiddle and  help me out to move forward@ Paresh Gami

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101996/discussion-between-paresh-gami-and-komal).